# Distribution Bounded

Tags: distributions, self-study, inference, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose Random variable  $X$  ~ Bernoulli $( p )$ .

How can we prove that

**$E[(X-p)^4]$ $\leq$ $p^4 + ( 1- p)^4$. ?**

I know that $E[(X-p)^2]$ = $Var[X]$ 
and  $E[X^2]= Var[X] + E[X]^2$

Comment: The expectation is the sum of two terms (which depend only on $p$), so why not write down this sum and maximize it?  The sum, when compared to the right hand side and simplified, becomes very simple indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Y = X - p$ then the characteristic function of $Y$ define as $\phi_Y(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tY}]$ is $e^{-tp} \phi_X(t)$ where $\phi_X(t)$ is th characteristic function of a Bernoulli and is $1-p + pe^t$.

Thus, $\phi_Y(t) = (1-p)e^{-tp} + pe^{t(1-p)}$.

It's easy to see that $\phi^{(n)}_Y(t) = p(1-p)^ne^{t(1-p)} + (-1)^np^n(1-p)e^{-tp}$.

It follows from $\mathbb{E}[(X-p)^n] = \phi_Y^{(n)}(0)$ that 
$$
\mathbb{E}[(X-p)^4] =  p(1-p)^4 + (1-p)p^4 \leq (1-p)^4 + p^4
$$

Comment: Why not just write the last line immediately from the definition of expectation? :-)

Comment: I feel dumb right now.... I guess I saw a moment of order n and directly thought of the characteristic function without even thinking about just writing the expectation

Comment: ... but your approach is perhaps more readily generalized!

Comment: @jbowman *E.g.,* it would be interesting to show the right hand side is an upper bound for *any* distribution of expectation $p$ supported on $[0,1]$ :-).

Comment: Thank you both ! It is always good to know all approaches!  Because I might use this moment generating function in other cases ( Eg. other distributions )